# Configure kotlin reflection, class.java doesn't work

Tags: reflection, kotlin

So I update kotlin to 1.0.0-rc-1036, and reflection is broken.

This code worked for me in beta:

```
ApiInterface::class.java
```

but now I get unresolved reference .java.

I found at documentation that kotlin-reflect is not part of standard library (I guess they moved it recently, but i didn't find anything in release notes).

So I added compile and classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.0.0-rc-1036' but it's still not working. How to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had Android Studio show this error, but the build still worked. It turns out that the AS database was out of sync. You can try deleting caches and restarting.

Comment: It actually compiled with that error. After deleting caches and restarting AS was still showing errors. Also, all kotlinx imports broke too, so I gave up and reverted to 1.0.0-beta-4589 and now everything it's working :/

Comment: @Gudin, first - for kotlinx add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-annotation'` in build.gradle, it is necessary for RC-1036. second - provide some code to understand your original problem, because `::class.java` syntax should work without `reflect`.

Comment: It is likely you have some mix of library versions and kotlin plugin versions that all do not line up.  If you check all of your dependencies you will find one is old, and therefore ignored by Kotlin (it actually is giving you a message somewhere that you are not seeing)

Comment: Someone asks this in kotlin slack every day, and it is the same answer, and 100% of the time a mismatch.

Comment: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` fixed the kotlinx, there's no `'kotlin-android-annotation'` plugin. `::class.java` is still shown as error, but it compiles and works